# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Sentiment Score'

Tags: python, pandas

I need to fix this, I've tried a lot of possibilities, but for some reason I don't know, nothing works.

It should be fixed by adding int(float(x)), but can't make it work.

I need to extract the symbol of this data, when the sentiment score is over 0.

data:

```
df    Negative  Neutral  Positive  Sentiment Score Symbol              Sector                       Industry    Market Cap                                Name
0   0.05721  0.87254   0.07026         0.028925    AIG  Financial Services          Insurance—Diversified  4.660713e+10  American International Group, Inc.
1   0.08450  0.83063   0.08484         0.007491    ALL  Financial Services  Insurance—Property & Casualty  3.632950e+10            The Allstate Corporation
```

and this is the code:

```py
df_sellable = []
for i in range(0,len(df_strong_sell)-1):
    b= int(float(df_strong_sell.iloc[[i+1,'Sentiment Score']]*1000000))
    print("b",(b))
    if (b) >= 0:
        
        stringer=str(df_strong_sell.iloc[[i+1,'Symbol']])
        df_sellable.append(stringer)
        df_sellable.append(stringer)
```

I need to extract the symbol of this data, when the sentiment score is over 0.

But I get this error:

`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Sentiment Score'`

Comment: the message is clear: you're converting a string to an integer, the contents of the string not being a valid integer

Comment: print / debug the values returned by the dataframe and see that it's not a numeric value.

Comment: Your code won't give the error you say it does -- if `df_strong_sell.iloc[[i+1,'Sentiment Score']]` is a string `'Sentiment Score'`, then that times `1000000` is a _very long_ string that repeats `'Sentiment Score'`  1 million times, and you'd get the error from the _`float`_ call, not the `int` call

Comment: Also, you don't need the loop at all! You seem to want `df_sellable = df.loc[df['Sentiment Score'].astype(float).shift(1) >= 0, 'Symbol'].tolist()`. You don't need to multiply by 1million, because all you do with that result is check if it's `>= 0`, and `x * 1_000_000 >= 0` implies `x >= 0` (Probably rename `df_sellable` because it isn't a dataframe!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you are tempted to use a `for` loop over a Dataframe, you should check yourself and verify that you are doing what `pandas` expects you to do.

Here is a way to get a list of symbols by filtering the Dataframe:

```py
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame({
    "Neutral": [0.87254, 0.83063],
    "Sentiment Score": [0.028925, 0.007491],
    "Symbol": ["AIG", "ALL"],
})

# ------------------
# a list of bools indicating row by row if a row passes the test.
# ------------------
passes_test = df["Sentiment Score"] > 0.0
print(passes_test.tolist())
# ------------------

# ------------------
# rows passing the test
# ------------------
passing_test = df[passes_test]
print(passing_test)
# ------------------

# ------------------
# Get the particular column
# ------------------
print(passing_test["Symbol"].tolist())
# ------------------

# ------------------
# More conventionally done in one go
# ------------------
ids = df[df["Sentiment Score"] > 0.0]["Symbol"].tolist()
print(ids)
# ------------------
```

That will give you:

```
['AIG', 'ALL']
['AIG', 'ALL']
```